# Django: Query self referencing objects with no child elements

Tags: python, django, self-reference

I have the following django model:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(maxlength=20)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True)
```

Note that the field `parent` is self referencing i.e. a category can have a parent.

How can I find all `Category` objects that have no child categories?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`isnull`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#isnull) with the [`related_query_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_query_name):

```
class Category(models.Model):
    # ...
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, related_name='children', related_query_name='child')

Category.objects.filter(child__isnull=True)
```

Here, I would recommend to specify at least a meaningful `related_name`!
If you specify only a `related_name`, the `related_query_name` defaults to that name (here: `children`). If you specify none of the two, the rqn defaults to the model name: `category`, **not** `category_set`

```
Category.objects.filter(category__isnull=True)  # not so informative
```

Comment: I used `Category.objects.filter(children__isnull=True)` and it works beautifully. Thanks.